# Remote Debugging can't be remove from Ionic/ Cordova App after Final Release Version

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, ionic-framework, remote-debugging

I am unable to remove my app from chrome://inspect remote debugging after final release version of apk! Anyone any idea how make it possible for security reason?

-I already signed it with my keystore file

Thanks

Comment: did u include `--release` when building? `ionic build --release android`

Comment: ya I make it all this things correct for sure!

Comment: are you using crosswalk?